# Вернуть JSON строку и преобразовать обратно в массив

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Я новичок в таком деле. Про ajax толком не понимаю, и надо было как-то вернуть значения из базы и заполнить ими поля у клиента. Прошу не кидаться тапками. ((

Пытаюсь организовать запрос. При нажатии на select в списке срабатывает функция отправки запроса. Запрос приходит на сервер, где генерируется ответ в виде массива, который я пытаюсь преобразовать в JSON...

```
    if (getcheck($_POST['getProduct']) == true)
{
        $id = getProduct;
        db_connect();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'");
        $productInfo = get_to_array($result);
        echo 'var arr = '.json_encode($productInfo);
}
```

а потом вернуть...

```
    var arr = {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        price: "",
        photo: "",
        category: ""
    };

function select()
{

        arr = [];

        var objSel = document.getElementById('spisok');

        //alert(objSel.options[objSel.selectedIndex].value);

        var hR = ('v' == '\v') ? new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
                   : new XMLHttpRequest ();
                   var params =  'getProduct=' + encodeURIComponent (objSel.options[objSel.selectedIndex].value);
        hR.open ("POST", 'function_db.php?', true);
        hR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        hR.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {if (hR.readyState == 4) getJSON(hR.responseText);}
        hR.send (params);
        //getJSON(hR.responseText)
}
```

В ответ ничего не выводится. ((

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вернуть JSON, *надо возвращать JSON.*
JSON, а не яваскрипт. Поэтому надо убрать ненужное `var arr` и сделать просто

```
echo  json_encode($productInfo);
```

Ну и, понятное дело, смотреть ответ в консоли разработчика.

Пользуясь случаем, порекламирую PDO для замены устаревших функций mysql. Помимо защиты от SQL инъекций, он еще и позволяет обходиться без таких велосипедов, как `get_to_array()`, поскольку в него они встроены из коробки.

```
    include 'pdo.php';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll());
```

- кода меньше, безопасности больше